# Pre allocation of for loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, memory-management

I'm new to loops and I have looked around the internet about pre-allocation but have hard time to know how to apply allocation on this problem. Therefore I wonder if someone can give any advice how to pre allocating this kind of loop in Matlab.

```
atest = [];
for k = 2:1000
    ab = 1+ (k)
    ac = ab +1
    atest = [atest, ac]
end

% expected dimensions of atest is a matrix of (1,999)
```

The basic idea is that I have some formulas that calculates for each loop (e.g. `ab` and `ac`). For next loop this formulas are added to `atest` matrix.
The final matrix, `artest` is my output which I know is going to have the dimensions of (1,999)

Comment: `atest =  zeros(1,999)` before going into the loop and and inside the loop `atest(k-1) = ac`. [This blobgpost](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) might be interesting for you to follow.

Comment: thank for help!! works wonderful. [SOLVED]

Comment: @Wiz If it's solved, consider marking an answer as the accepted one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another variant to Divakar's answer (thanks a lot!) that I found out is:

```
atest = zeros(1,1000)
for k = 2:1000
    ab = 1 + (k)
    ac = ab + 1
    atest(:,k) = ac
end
```

Since the matrix of `k` starts at column 2, the first column of `atest` will be empty (filled with 0).
Therefore I might suggest to use `atest = NaN(1,1000)` instead to pre-allocate to easy see "missing values".
Notice that we use 1000 instead of 999 since the allocation depends on end value of k matrix

Comment: Considering that `atest` is a vector, `atest(k) = ac` is more efficient.